# How deep should liquidtight flex conduit be burried?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

How deep should liquidtight flex cable be burried for a 75 ft run for an outdoor circuit? I see pvc conduit is at 18 inches.

[image: picture of liquidtight conduit]

Comment: Don't use liquid tight for direct burial, not to code in some types (many) and WAY more expensive.

Comment: @EdBeal I am on the fence between that and PVC. I came across this and started looking into it. The package does however state it complies with NEC 356.

Comment: It's also not liquid tight.  Keeping water out of underground conduit is totally unrealistic, unless you pressurize it with nitrogen or something.  (Since air would condense).

Comment: If you're going to dig a trench, why not both? Pull some comm wire while you're at it. Besides, you want a shovel to have hit the PVC first...

Comment: Start adding the liquid tight ends and it gets much more expensive plus wire is harder to pull in LT than PVC.

Answer (score 5):

> **356.10 Uses Permitted.** LFNC shall be permitted to be used in exposed or concealed locations for the following purposes:
>
> Informational Note: Extreme cold may cause some types of nonmetallic conduits to become brittle and therefore more sus-ceptible to damage from physical contact.
>
> (1) Where flexibility is required for installation, operation, or maintenance.
>
> (2) Where protection of the contained conductors is required from vapors, liquids, or solids.
>
> (3) For outdoor locations where listed and marked as suit-able for the purpose.
>
> (4) For direct burial where listed and marked for the purpose.

Notice number 4.

Here is an excerpt from the UL Whitebook concerning LFNC

> **Flexible Nonmetallic Conduit, Liquid-tight (DXOQ) USE AND INSTALLATION**
>
> This category covers liquid-tight flexible nonmetallic conduit, in trade sizes 3/8 in. to 4 (metric designators 12 to 103) inclusive, for installation in accordance with Article 356 of ANSI/NFPA 70, ‘‘National Electrical Code'' (NEC).
>
> This product may also be used for installation of conductors for electric signs and outline lighting in accordance with the NEC.
>
> PRODUCT MARKINGS Liquid-tight flexible nonmetallic conduit suitable for direct burial and in poured concrete is marked ‘‘Direct Burial,'' ‘‘ Burial,'' ‘‘Dir Burial'' or ‘‘Dir Bur.'' Liquid-tight flexible nonmetallic conduit suitable for use outdoors is marked ‘‘Outdoor.''

**According to Table 300.5 column 3 you would need 18" of cover. If you have a 120volt circuit that is GFCI protected you can reduce the cover to 12".**

Notice the table reads "minimum cover requirements" NOT burial depth. With small raceways this is insignificant but larger raceway should be measured to the top of the raceway not the depth of the trench.

[Note: I had previously cited Article 350 which is LFMC not LFNC and referred to manufacturers information for burial depth which is actually covered by Table 300.5 of the code. Upon re-reading the Code I edited this answer accordingly adding the citation to the UL Whitebook. Hopefully this clarifies some things.]

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: "Direct Burial" may not be on the package but "Crush resistant" may, amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - Where in the code does it say you can use "crush resistant" where it must be "For direct burial where listed and marked for the purpose."

Comment: What else would crush resistant indicate?

Comment: Physical hazards; like running into it with a skid loader.

Comment: With regards to this specific product - SouthWire makes four varieties of LFNM conduit.  In the description, three list bullet points as "crush resistant", one does not.  Those that do further specify in the longer details: " For direct burial and encased in concrete. "

Comment: You think manufacturers would put "crush resistant" on a package to declare, "HEY, I'M SAFE TO SUBJECT TO PHYSICAL TRAUMA"?  As opposed to say, "I'm safe to subject to long term high pressure stresses underground"?  R-U-SRS?

Comment: "Marked" means the manufacturer must clearly mark the product or provide documentation with the product to clearly identify the product as suitable for the purpose. Crush resistant is not at all related to direct burial.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo - That's pretty much what the code says. *Where subject to physical trauma, you have to use ridged or crush resistant.*

Comment: I'm sorry but I seriously doubt that any conduit is designed with the predetermined intention to stand up to high impact blows conveying potentially thousands of pounds of impact force.   Further I've supported my previous statement by pointing out the context in which that term appears on this specific product.

Comment: Thanks for the response and comments. Looking at the package on the picture, it does state, "Ideal for wet and outdoor locations & direct burial" and also, states on the package it complies with NEC Article 356.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo if a crush resistant conduit was also fit and listed for direct burial, **why on earth would the manufacturer *keep that a secret*** and not simply *mark* it as such?  Occam's Razor: they can't because **it's not** fit......  I get where most crush resistant conduit also says wet location.  Most THHN wire is also THWN-2. The marks still matter, THHN is still not legal in wet locations.  Don't replace skill with habit.

Comment: @eaglei22 then you are golden. Now the burial depth is another issue but if you go 24" you will be good.

Comment: @harper Who said it was being kept a secret?  I JUST TOLD YOU that the product info online states suitable for burial.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo because you just found out.  Before that you were saying `"Direct Burial" may not be on the package but "Crush resistant" may, amounts to the same thing. – The Evil Greebo 2 days ago` Claiming crush resistant *implied* direct burial. You yourself are the one who floated the notion that a mfgr might say CR and not mention DB and that makes it all right to use.

Comment: When Mazura challenged you, you said `What else would crush resistant indicate? – The Evil Greebo 2 days ago` And `You think manufacturers would put "crush resistant" on a package to declare, "HEY, I'M SAFE TO SUBJECT TO PHYSICAL TRAUMA"? As opposed to say, "I'm safe to subject to long term high pressure stresses underground"? R-U-SRS? – The Evil Greebo 2 days ago`

Comment: You also were dubious that "crush resistant" would be a meaningful property by itself (honestly I kinda see your point there) `I'm sorry but I seriously doubt that any conduit is designed with the predetermined intention to stand up to high impact blows conveying potentially thousands of pounds of impact force. Further I've supported my previous statement by pointing out the context in which that term appears on this specific product. – The Evil Greebo 2 days ago`  So I can see why you might think CR might imply DB, but I've never seen Code be vague or inferential like that.

Comment: Yes, I just found out - because I'd never looked up this product before.  On this product, it amounts to the same thing.  I also agree that it doesn't satisfy code's labeling requirement.  I also agree that code is not unclear.  We're not talking about code, we're talking about product manufacturer labeling which can be unclear.  I still stand by my question - what ELSE would "crush resistant" stand for?  Because the idea that it stands for "safe to hit with a skid loader or otherwise subject to severe impacts" is flat out absurd.

Answer (score 5):

With all the fuss no one answered the question. The answer is if listed it can be at 18" the same as conduit. I would not use in this case but since listed it would be legal.